# Print formatted strings with variables while synchronously iterating multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, transpose, string-interpolation, array-map

It is known that `array_combine` is used only for two arrays. For example

```
$name = array('John','Brian','Raj');
$salary = array('500','1000','2000');
$details = array_combine($name, $salary);
foreach($details AS $name => $salary){
    echo $name."'s salary is ".$salary."<br/>";
}
```

Let add 2 arrays in this list

```
$dpart = array('HTML','CSS','PHP');
$address = array('Floor 3','Floor 5','Floor 6');
```

In that case, only `array_combine()` is not enough, so I found `array_map()` is the better solution here. But how to echo `array_map()` result? How to access values of array generated by `array_map()` and fetch according individual requirement.

```
$details = array_map(function($item) {
    return array_combine(['name', 'salary', 'dpart', 'address'], $item);
}, array_map(null, $name, $salary, $dpart, $address));
```

Now requirement is to access all four arrays with individual values. For example

`$name."'s salary is ".$salary.", address is ".$address.", depart is ".$dpart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access result simply using `foreach`. Loop `$details` as

```
foreach($details as $item) {
    $name    = $item['name'];
    $salary  = $item['salary'];
    $dpart   = $item['dpart'];
    $address = $item['address'];
    echo $name."'s salary is ".$salary.", address is ".$address.", depart is ".$dpart."<br/>";
}
```

Or without the assignment within the loop:

```
foreach($details as $item)
    print "{$item['name']}'s salary is {$item['name']}, address is {$item['dpart']}, depart is {$item['address']}<br/>";
```

Comment: Note the first example clobbers the initial arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It may be just as simple to not combine these:

```
<?php
$name    = array('John','Brian','Raj');
$salary  = array('500','1000','2000');
$dpart   = array('HTML','CSS','PHP');
$address = array('Floor 3','Floor 5','Floor 6');

foreach($name as $k => $v)
    printf(
        "%s's salary is %d, address is %s, depart is %s\n",
        $name[$k],
        $salary[$k],
        $dpart[$k],
        $address[$k]
    );
```

Output:

```
John's salary is 500, address is HTML, depart is Floor 3
Brian's salary is 1000, address is CSS, depart is Floor 5
Raj's salary is 2000, address is PHP, depart is Floor 6
```

You can loop through your array_map, and use list, or the item indexes:

```
foreach(array_map(null, $name, $salary, $dpart, $address) as $item) {
    list($n, $s, $d, $a) = $item;
    print "$n's salary is $s, address is $d, depart is $a\n";
}
```

Comment: That's cool, maybe first way would be faster also than combining, isn't it ?

Comment: I doubt speed is a concern here.  But it's less array wrangling.  Problem with many arrays like that, is that they must have same items and correct corresponding elements.  Could you not start with a multi-dimensional array to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a native function which allows you to craft a string with placeholders and pass in an array of data to replace those placeholders -- `vprint()` (or its silent sibling: `vsprintf()`).

After "transposing" the data from the four input arrays, collect the column of data using variadic syntax (`...`) and feed it to the printing function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jf3Kb))

```
print_r(
    array_map(
        fn(...$col) => vsprintf("%s's salary is %d, depart is %s, address is %s", $col),
        $name, $salary, $dpart, $address
    )
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John's salary is 500, depart is HTML, address is Floor 3
    [1] => Brian's salary is 1000, depart is CSS, address is Floor 5
    [2] => Raj's salary is 2000, depart is PHP, address is Floor 6
)
```